# Сравнить или преобразовать два списка

Tags: python

Есть два списка. Подскажите пожалуйста, как сравнить (или преобразовать и сравнить) эти два списка и вывести элементы списка `list_1` которых нет в `list_2`?
я прям новичок новичок, так что не ругайтесь сильно

`list_1 = [[1, 7, 0], [1, 7, 0], [1, 7, 0], [3, 1, 7], [1, 7, 0], [1, 7, 0], [3, 1, 7], [3, 1, 7]] <class 'list'>`

`list_2 =[(2, 7, 0), (7, 2), (7, 1, 7), (1, 3, 7), (0, 7, 1), (7, 1, 3), (1, 7, 0), (3, 1, 7), (3, 2, 7)] <class 'list'>`

Comment: Строго говоря во втором списке кортежи, а в первом списки. Смело выводите первый список целиком. Или исправьте вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[tio.run](https://tio.run/##jY1BCsMgEEX3nuIvFVwkcdFVTyIuEjBUKCpqwZ7eOqkhq0JX/83w/kx8l0fwqrUVd2g9S9wkJiPxA5UETX8JJxq20XG@fC0hwXsuI0kh7KkGToc4X4IawllXV60j3RWGsdy/ZFv4JliyNOiKPSRUOI8VbocPBeUVn5ZXQcvcWzE5X3gviNY@)

```
a = [[1, 7, 0], [1, 7, 0], [1, 7, 0], [3, 1, 7], [1, 7, 0], [1, 7, 0], [3, 1, 7], [3, 1, 7]]
b = [(2, 7, 0), (7, 2), (7, 1, 7), (1, 3, 7), (0, 7, 1), (7, 1, 3), (1, 7, 0), (3, 1, 7), (3, 2, 7)]

s = set(b)
res = [x for x in a if not tuple(x) in s]

print(res)
```

```
[]
```

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, невнимательно прочитал. Исправил.